# RhinoMock says: "Type doesn't match the return type"

Tags: .net, unit-testing, c#-4.0, rhino-mocks

I've written such class:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int LowLimit { get; set; }

    internal virtual bool CheckLimit(int measurement)
    {
        return LowLimit <= measurement;
    }
}
```

And a test for it:

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
var limit = mocks.StrictMock<A>();

Expect.Call(limit.CheckLimit(2)).Return(true).Repeat.Once();
mocks.ReplayAll();
limit.CheckLimit(2);
mocks.VerifyAll();
```

And it fails with:
System.InvalidOperationException : Type 'System.Boolean' doesn't match the return type 'System.Int32' for method 'A.get_LowLimit();'

But when I replace internal keyword for CheckLimit method to public, it works ok.
Why it is behaiving like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using an external library (**StrictMock**), then it can't access any of your internal methods.

It looks like the **StrictMock** implementation is trying to use A's **CheckLimit**, but because it can't find an implementation probably uses its own implementation which uses A's **LowLimit**.

Comment: Strange. If it can't access CheckLimit, how does it know that CheckLimit uses LowLimit inside? And what is the solution? I need to have internal keywork there :(

Comment: Ah, anyway I got it, so thanks. I've added [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocks.NormalName)] to my assably and it worked. Thanks